# What is single point continuity?

Tags: calculus, continuity, differential

According to my textbook ,

> Function should be continuous only at one point and to be defined everywhere.

For example ,

$$F(x)=\begin{cases} x\ \text{if} \ x\in Q \\-x\ \text{if} \ x\notin Q
\end{cases}$$

The above example is continuous at $x = 0$ and defined everywhere.

My question is what does this means to be defined everywhere and how a function can be continuous at one point?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=f(0)=0$

Comment: It's unclear why your textbook says function should be continuous only at one point. There are lots of functions such that the statement is false.

Comment: The statements "domain of a function $f$ is $A$" and "function $f$ is defined at all points of $A$ and nowhere else" are equivalent. Here your function has $\mathbb{R} $ as its domain and we usually say (in this case) that function is defined everywhere.

Comment: @ArcticChar : maybe the textbook is asking (or providing) an example of such a function. It is not supposed to be result which would holds for all functions.

Comment: May be you can share title/author of your textbook?

Comment: @ArcticChar, I think that is the definition for single point continuity.

Comment: As mentioned by J. W. Tanner, $f$ being continuous at $x=0$ means that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=f(0)=0$. I think you can try to get an intuitive idea why by trying to imagine the graph.

Comment: I found "skills in mathematics", unfortunately unsearchable, but "Coordinate geometry"  - I doubt, is this that book in which is your question? If yes, which volume and page?

Comment: @Curiousminded, seems it's correct book now, but page is 470. I write addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at definition of continuity using neighborhood conception (John M.H. Olmsted - Advanced calculus-Prentice Hall (1961), case for single variable on page 43, multiple - page 186 ):

$f$ is continuous at some point $a$ iif $f$ is defined in $a$ and holds $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition for points from $a$'s neighborhood in which function **is defined**. I.e. definition puts restriction on intersection of domain of $f$ and $a$'s neighborhood.

Using such definition continuity for function can be defined, together with definition in limit point of domain, also in isolated point of domain - in such cases function is automatically continuous and we can say, that it is **continuous at single point**.

**Addition**.

How it became known from the comments. We are talking about the book AMIT M Agarwal - A Textbook of Differential Calculus, Chapter 6, page 470. Under the title "Function continuous only at one point and defined everywhere. (Single Point Continuity)". **eg,(ii)** is function brought in OP.

1. It is defined everywhere, obviously, because $\mathbb{Q} \cup (\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{R}$.
2. It's continuous at $x=0$, because $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)=0$. I'll brought proof by definition: we need $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0, |x| \lt \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(0)|=|f(x)| = |x| \lt \varepsilon$ , which is obvious, if we take $\delta=\varepsilon$.
3. It's discontinous for any $x_0 \ne 0$, because we can find sequence of rational numbers $x_n \to x_0$ and sequence of irrational numbers $y_n \to x_0$. For first will be $f(x_n)=x_n \to x_0$ and for second $f(y_n)=-y_n \to -x_0$, which makes continuity impossible.

Comment: Excuse me sir , thank you for you time but actually the symbols and language you used in your answer , I am not familiar with them . I am a high school student just started with this topic and the solution you provided is going above my head honestly , I am sorry if it sounds rude to you .

Comment: Write, please, which part you do not understand and I'll rephrase it.

Comment: Glad to be helpful (by the way, you can up vote it also, if/when find this fair). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Continuity is DEFINED pointwise, i.e. a function is continuous at a point $a$ in its domain if and only if $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists,  $f(a)$ is defined, and the two are equal, i.e.
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$$

We extend from this the notion of a function being continuous on a subset of the domain (Typically intervals in the terms of real functions, though not always) to mean that the function is continuous at every point in that subset. (Or the whole domain if it works for the entire domain)

A function is defined on its domain, that's the set of inputs. Here the author was showing you how you could have a function that is continuous only at 1 point.  Typically we visualize continuity as "being able to draw a graph without picking up your pen",  but that fails on weirder stuff.

For example, the function $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational and $f(x)=\frac 1 q$  if $x=\frac p q$ where $\gcd (p,q)=1$ is a weird one that is continuous at every irrational  and discontinuous at every  rational.   The reason why for that is you can get close enough to any irrational such that all the denominators of fractions near it are as large as you like,  so you can make the function as small as you want.

Comment: Popcorn function in last para  :)

Comment: @Koro Yeah, I had Spivak for my undergraduate analysis course and I've seen that question pop up a few times recently here, so it was on my mind as a good pathological example.